# Single sign on with different domain using $cookie_domain in Drupal without using modules?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, single-sign-on

Drupal:

single log-in must be on the same domain. For example:

```
dev1.example.com
dev2.example.com

$cookie_domain = '.example.com';
```

Now the above sites getting sinle sign on . works good .

But in my case I Have ,

```
dev1.needthings.com
dev2.example.com
```

Now , can i able to achieve the single sign on with using **$cookie_domain**?

Note: 
     $cookie_domain which is available in settings.php in drupal 
Pls help..
Thanks in  Advance...

Answer (score 0):

If the two domains point to the same Drupal site you can use `$cookie_domain` to make them share the cookie. But if the sites are not the same, with the same database etc, you can't use `$cookie_domain`. In that case you would probably need a central login mechanisme, like SO has with all the affiliate sites.